# find: How to efficiently search for big list of filenames

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, find

I need to find a few hundred files, where the base names are provided by some list (let's call it `baseNames`). I then need to search for these base names + three given extensions.

*Example:* Assume one of the base names extracted from the input list is `FOO` and the given extensions are `.txt`, `.csv`, `.py`. Then I need to find `FOO.txt`, `FOO.csv`, `FOO.py`.

The current approach in my bash script is as follows:

```bsh
for bn in ${baseNames}; do
  find ${searchDir} '(' -name "$bn.txt" -o -name "$bn.csv" -o -name "$bn.py" ')'
done
```

This works but is quite inefficient. For every base name I need to run `find` on the whole `searchDir` again, which contains quite a lot of files and hence takes a while.

***Is there a way to provide a list of files that `find` should search for, via options or pipes?***

Obviously I am aware of `-name ... -or`, but it's also obvious that this approach is unrealistic if I have a couple of hundred files.
For simplicity, you may also leave aside the extensions. Just assume I have a huge list of files that I want to search for as input to `find`.

Comment: if you have a list, use an array not an unquoted string.

Comment: @cas: Don't get it, sorry. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array.  e.g.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

baseNames=(FOO BAR BAZ)

findNames=('(')
for bn in "${baseNames[@]}"; do
  for ext in txt csv py; do
    findNames+=("$bn.$ext" '-o' '-name')
  done
done
# replace the final '-o' and '-name' in the array with a close parenthesis
unset 'findNames[-1]'
findNames[-1]=')'
# If using a version of bash before v4.3, use:
#unset 'findNames[${#findNames[@]}-1]'
#findNames[${#findNames[@]}-1]=')'


declare -p findNames
```

Output from the `declare -p` is (some line feeds and spaces added to break it up and make it more readable):

```
declare -a findNames=(
  [0]="("
    [1]="-name" [2]="FOO.txt" [3]="-o" [4]="-name" [5]="FOO.csv"
    [6]="-o" [7]="-name" [8]="FOO.py" [9]="-o" [10]="-name" [11]="BAR.txt"
    [12]="-o" [13]="-name" [14]="BAR.csv" [15]="-o" [16]="-name" [17]="BAR.py"
    [18]="-o" [19]="-name" [20]="BAZ.txt" [21]="-o" [22]="-name" [23]="BAZ.csv"
    [24]="-o" [25]="-name" [26]="BAZ.py"
  [27]=")"
)
```

---

To use the array with `find`, you'd do something like:

```
searchDir="./"
find "$searchDir" "${findNames[@]}"
```

This would result in the following find command being executed (line breaks added for readability):

```
find ./ ( -name FOO.txt -o -name FOO.csv -o -name FOO.py \
  -o -name BAR.txt -o -name BAR.csv -o -name BAR.py \
  -o -name BAZ.txt -o -name BAZ.csv -o -name BAZ.py )
```

The `(` and `)` don't need to be escaped here because the shell treats them as just literal arguments (the array has already been expanded by bash), not an instruction to start a sub-shell. If you were typing them into a shell, you'd have to escape or quote them.

Comment: Alternatively, use `grep`.  e.g. `find "$searchDir" -type f | grep -E '/(FOO|BAR|BAZ)\.(txt|csv|py)$'`.   or GNU find's `-regex` or `-iregex` options: `find "$searchDir" -type f -regextype awk -regex '/(FOO|BAR|BAZ)\.(txt|csv|py)$'`

Comment: just noticed a typo in my comment.  The `-regex` pattern should start with `'.*/`, not just `'/`.

Comment: I had to used the `grep` solution, because the system I have to work on uses bash 4.1.2, which doesn't recognize `findNames[-1]` unfortunately. But I tried your solution on a newer bash version, where it works as expected. Looks like I need to brush up my knowledge about arrays in bash, though.

Comment: For compatibility with bash before v4.3, you can use `unset 'findNames[${#findNames[@]}-1]'` followed by `findNames[${#findNames[@]}-1]=')'`.    This still works in newer versions of bash, the much shorter `arrayname[-1]` from 4.3+ is convenient, but not essential.  See [Remove the last element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8247497/137158) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The following `sh` script reads base names from the file `names`, which contains one name per line (names should be quoted if they contain spaces etc.), and calls an in-line `sh -c` script with batches of these (50 at a time).  I'm dividing the input into batches, just in case the data expands to a list that is too long for a single invocation of `find` (we need to construct commands with a total combined length of more than `n` time the length of the input data, where `n` is the number of filename suffixes to look for).

The in-line script constructs an "OR list" of `-name` tests based on the given base names for `find`.  Each base name is entered into the list with variations for the three filenames suffixes `.txt`, `.csv`, and `.py`.

The list is maintained in the list of positional parameters, `"$@"`.

Once the list is complete, `find` is called to find the regular files matching these names, in or under some directory `$topdir`.

```bsh
topdir=$HOME

<names xargs -L 50 sh -c '
        topdir=$1; shift

        for name do
                for suffix in txt csv py; do
                        set -- "$@" -o -name "$name.$suffix"
                done
                shift  # shift off current base name
        done
        shift  # shift off the initial "-o"

        find "$topdir" -type f \( "$@" \) -print
' sh "$topdir"
```

Run with a lower number than 50 and with `sh -x -c` in place of `sh -c` to see what commands the in-line script is actually executing.

---

If you want to use named arrays and the `bash` shell:

```bsh
topdir=$HOME

<names xargs -L 50 bash -c '
        topdir=$1; shift
        unset tests

        for name do
                for suffix in txt csv py; do
                        tests+=( -o -name "$name.$suffix" )
                done
        done

        find "$topdir" -type f \( "${tests[@]:1}" \) -print
' bash "$topdir"
```

Here, an array, `tests`, is used instead of the list of positional parameters.  The strange-looking `"${tests[@]:1}"` expands to the list of elements of the array, except for the first element (which will be `-o`).

Although, if you're using `bash`, you may just as well use its globbing facilities (originally inherited from the `ksh` shell):

```bsh
shopt -s extglob globstar dotglob nullglob

topdir=$HOME

printf -v pattern '%s/**/@(%s).@(txt|csv|py)' "$topdir" "$(paste -s -d '|' - <names)"

eval "pathnames=( $pattern )"

# The following loop is only for illustration.
# If you really just wanted to list the names, use
#     printf '%s\n' "${pathnames[@]}"

for pathname in "${pathnames[@]}"; do
        printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
done
```

This constructs an extended globbing pattern from the contents of the `names` file.  This pattern may end up looking like

```
/home/myself/**/@(name1|name2|name3).@(txt|csv|py)
```

... which would match the names that you presumably are interested in.  Note though that you would have to do any file type tests yourself in the loop (to sort out regular files from directories etc.)

The shell options set at the top of the script enables the use of the extend pattern `@(...|...)` (`extglob`), the use of `**` to match down into subdirectories (`globstar`), allows us to names that are hidden or located in hidden subdirectories (`dotglob`).  We also set `nullglob` ta make the pattern disappear if there are no matches at all.

Comment: This question is specifically for bash.  Why use `set --` when bash supports arrays?   `set --` is an ugly hack for ancient shells which don't have arrays, repurposing ARGV to be a pretend-array.

Comment: @cas Bash supports manipulating the list of positional parameters with `set --` too, and my code works in `bash` with no need for modifications.  You may change `sh -c` into `bash -c` if you wish.  I will add a `bash` variation for you in a short while, but it's going to be a bit more verbose.

Comment: yes, this `set --` hack works in bash.  but you don't need to do it, because bash supports arrays. As does ksh. and zsh.  and any other non-ancient bourne-like sh (yes, posix sh and dash and ash all qualify as "ancient".  deliberately so).   I already wrote my own answer based on bash arrays.

Comment: @cas I would use arrays if I needed to. There is no real need here, but I do realize some people find it more comfortable to deal with named arrays than with the slightly mysterious list of positional parameters.

Comment: Could you try to be just a little more condescending, please? I wasn't quite insulted enough.   It's not "mysterious", this `set --` trick is and always was an ugly hack. One of the main reasons why modern shells got arrays was so that we didn't have to use such ugly hacks any more.  So we could programmatically build arg lists for commands without having to deal with all the associated white space and quoting hassles.  Arrays work, without hackery.

Comment: @cas Sorry. I thought your main concern was with readability and how easy it was to understand the code, and I do think that the list of positional parameters _is_ mysterious to many people, so they _would_ want to use named arrays instead. I did most certainly not intend to insult in any way. In fact, I'm happy that you pointed it out as I'm usually not using arrays in my answers unless I have to. As for "ugly hack", using `set --` is at least portable to any POSIX shell that I'm aware of, which is why I'm using it.

Comment: @cas As you may have noticed, I have added a `bash` variation of my code as a direct consequence of you pointing out the "ancient" nature of my first piece of code. Thank you again for bringing this to my attention, and do feel free to point this out to me again in the future as I'm bound to forget.

Comment: `-L 50` is to take words from 50 lines, it still processes whitespace and quoting in those lines. To process 50 newline delimited words, you'd need GNU xargs and `xargs -rd '\n' -n 50` or use dirty and unreliable hacks POSIXly.

Answer (score 1):

With zsh (you are using zsh syntax in your code when you're leaving those parameter expansions unquoted):

```
names=(foo bar baz)
exts=(txt csv py)
print -rC1 - **/(${(~j[|])names}).${(~j[|])exts})(ND)
```

Where `${(j[|])array}` joins the elements of the array with `|`, a `|` considered as a glob operator thanks to `~`. `N` for `nullglob`, `D` for `dotglob`.

Or of course do directly:

```
print -rC1 - **/(foo|bar|baz).(cvs|py|txt)(ND)
```

If names and extensions are found one per line in some files, use

```
names=( ${(f)"$(< names.txt)"} )
 exts=( ${(f)"$(< exts.txt)"}  )
```

You could also do:

```
print -rC1 - **/$^names.$^exts(ND)
```

But that would be a lot less efficient as that would expand a recursive glob for each combination of name + ext.

To use `find` to do the searching:

```
cmd=(find . '(') or=()
for name ($^names.$^exts) cmd+=($or -name ${(b)name}) or=(-o)
cmd+=(')')
$cmd
```